# how to go to another ViewController after successful login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios6

I am newbie for iPhone application. I have followed [**this tutorial**](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-receive-data-from-the-server-in-iphone/) for login from iPhone.

I have php file as below.

**index.php**

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['uname'];

if ($user == 'user') {
    echo "Welcome to my site...";
} else {
    echo "Invalid User";
}
?>
```

When I run application and enter username as **user** and password as some text, I get output as **Welcome to my site...**.

Now instead of welcome message, I wanna go to my welcome screen i.e. View Controller that I have on story board. Any idea how to get this done?

Full code is as below.

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    greeting.text= @"";
    NSString* username = nameInput.text;
    NSString* pass = passInput.text;
    greeting.hidden = NO;
    if([nameInput.text isEqualToString:@"" ] && [passInput.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        greeting.text = @"Please enter username and password.";
        [nameInput resignFirstResponder];
        [passInput resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    if([nameInput.text isEqualToString:@"" ])
    {
        greeting.text = @"Please enter username.";
        [nameInput resignFirstResponder];
        [passInput resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }

    if([passInput.text isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        greeting.text = @"Please enter password.";
        [nameInput resignFirstResponder];
        [passInput resignFirstResponder];
        return;
    }


    NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"uname=%@&pwd=%@",username,pass];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/PhPTesting/index.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        indicator.hidden = NO;
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {

    }

    [nameInput resignFirstResponder];
    [passInput resignFirstResponder];
    nameInput.text = nil;
    passInput.text = nil;
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    greeting.text = loginStatus;
    [loginStatus release];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
    indicator.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this :

```
if ([loginStatus isEqualToString:@"Welcome to my site..."]) {
    // Show welcome view controller
    NextViewController *nextViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNextView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
} else {
    greeting.text = @"Login was not correct";
}
```

Here , @"myNextView" is a NextView Identifier.

Comment: this works with Navigation controller... what if I don't want to use Navigation controller...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the result

```
if ([loginStatus isEqualToString:@"Welcome to my site..."]) {
    // Show welcome view controller
} else {
    greeting.text = @"Login was not correct";
}
```

I also suggest returning a more helpful string via PHP

---

### UPDATE

There are tons of tutorials for presenting a new view.

Check out this here: [Programatically Switching Views in Cocoa Touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370055/programatically-switching-views-in-cocoa-touch)

Comment: but what code to write at `// Show welcome view controller`. I know this, but I need what code should I write so that main screen would get replaced with the new view controller.

Comment: I don't get anything from that link... Can you provide code for me so that I can understand...

Comment: Just call `presentModalViewController:animated:` on the view controller you want show.

Comment: You have to first subclass UIViewController, so you can make a custom view. Make a quick google search, you'll get much better answers.